# Python3 - Averaging values in one list if values in another list are sufficiently close

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Take two example lists (or arrays):

```
J = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0]
B = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 6.0, 7.0, 0.5, 0.6, 8.0]
```

My ultimate target: if any elements of J are identical, then the duplicate values should removed, with only one appearing. Furthermore, the corresponding elements indexed elements in B should be averaged over, which leaves one with two lists that are probably smaller, but with no duplicated J values. If there are no elements that are identical, then of course the list should be untouched. For the example above, the 1.0 is duplicated 3 times, and hence the corresponding B values (0.7, 0.8 and 0.9) should all three be averaged over. Similarly, the 4.0 is duplicated twice, and hence 0.5 and 0.6 should be averaged over.

The desired result:

```
J_desired = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
B_desired = [0.8, 6.0, 7.0, 0.55, 8.0]
```

I have tried methods based on differences between the elements in J and looked into mapping/list comprehensions. I tried to work a method which groups distinct elements in J together and then group corresponding elements in B, and then average over each tuple in the list, but I couldn't understand how to map between the two. Any help would be appreciated! The lists are never massive, but I couldn't think of a "Pythonic" way of approaching this.

Any method should still be okay if there are no duplicates, or elements work with bigger lists as well, e.g:

```
J = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25860967184801387, 0.17227115716753025, 0.17227115716753025, 0.17227115716753025, 0.13078583765112264, 0.10352331606217618, 0.0835587219343696, 0.0835587219343696, 0.0835587219343696, 0.06857858376511226, 0.06857858376511226]

B = [0.0, 0.03622632071144814, 0.07245264142289629, 3.550179423214222, 6.194700815988386, 6.230927136338296, 6.267153456688205, 8.875448558035552, 11.519969979732812, 14.092038724576383, 14.128265044926295, 14.164491365276204, 16.700333825923735, 16.736560146273646]
```

Comment: so basically define a tolerance for each value in `B` average those values, and get the average of the corresponding `j` values in the first list?

Comment: Or almost the inverse; for all equal `j` values, represent one of them with the average of corresponding `b` indexes to those values?

Comment: Other way around; if the J values are sufficiently close, then average over those values, and the corresponding B values to those

Comment: ill try toying with some code for that to see what I can do :)

Comment: @Ironkey the direct inverse of the first comment, not so much the second

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm sure it's a trivial comprehension and mapping question but I can't see the easy route to the goal!

Comment: Depending on data quality, J might not be generally always descending/sorted. However, the close pairs will always be adjacent to each other, so I'll always be concerned with addressing say, J=2.6, 2.6, 2.6 and looking to find the corresponding B values and average over those

Comment: Why don't you track the indices of the duplicate entries? You could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for that. Then you loop over array  `J` and check if that entry occurs more than once (using Counter). If they do you map them against array `B` and see what the indices are. You then collect the values at the corresponding indices to average the values and put them in a new array. Finally, remove the duplicate values from array `J`

Comment: @k88 - this approach that you've outlined was precisely my thought process! I had seen Collections been mentioned in a few SO posts but didn't think it was directly useful to this. I will look into Counter shortly; thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works if J's are not sorted, but losses initial order is they were sorted (order will be preserved for python3.6+).

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for i_j, i_b in zip(j, b):
    result[i_j].append(i_b)

new_j = list(result.keys())
new_b = [sum(result[i_j]) / len(result[i_j]) for i_j in new_j]
```

As each J value corresponds to B, it pretty much looks like key-value relation or a `dict` in other words. The fact that J may have duplicates only means that there is now multiple B values per single J value. So we need to collect all of B's per J. To do so, i used `defaultdict(list)` - if a key is not in the dictionary yet, it makes it default value to empty list, this removes overhead of need to manually check if key is present in result and setting it to empty list if it is not.
The rest is simple: iterate over key-value pair and collect the data. Once it is done, we have a dict of all B's per each J. Converting those to lists and getting average is trivial.

Comment: Hi Nirvana - thanks for your answers! I'm afraid I'm getting some errors when I run both of your codes, one relating to division by zero and another relating to list() needing some arguments (I'm on Python3)... the other answer does precisely what I need, but I can see the clear theory of your answer; I might look into implementing something like this if I need some more complex work! Thank you for your kind help though

Comment: For reference; error for first part:
    result = defaultdict(list())
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
and error for second part:
result_b.append(sum(curr_b_list) / len(curr_b_list))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: My bad, never actually test my answers. Removed first one and fixed second. It works now and results are as expected.

Comment: Fascinating... thank you for your help. Would you mind explaining how the answer works? What is the purpose of the result dictionary? The documentation is quite confusing...

Comment: @Brad i've added an explanation. Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `groupby` for this along with some other functions and finally remove duplicates from `J`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

j = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0]
b = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 6.0, 7.0, 0.5, 0.6, 8.0]

b_desired = [sum(i)/len(i) for i in [list(list(zip(*g))[1]) for k, g in groupby(zip(j, b), itemgetter(0))]]
j_desired = list(dict.fromkeys(j))
```

**output**

```
print(j_desired)
print([round(i, 2) for i in b_desired]) #you could just print B but this looks a little cleaner for output
```

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[0.8, 6.0, 7.0, 0.55, 8.0]
```

---

**So, what's going on here?**

well im going to assume you're having problems with that initial comprehension, so lets go through that!

first, let's analyze what `groupby` does. Groupby is extremely useful when used in conjunction with itemgetter for things like this (if you don't know what itemgetter is please go read the docs on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), it's extremely useful!)

Groupby will group elements of nested list/tuple like structures using a key (which is why we use the itemgetter() operator)

```
for k, g in groupby(zip(j, b), itemgetter(0)):
    print(list(zip(*g)))
```

```
[(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (0.7, 0.8, 0.9)]
[(2.0,), (6.0,)]
[(3.0,), (7.0,)]
[(4.0, 4.0), (0.5, 0.6)]
[(5.0,), (8.0,)]
```

as you can see all of the elements are grouped into lists of tuples; the first tuple being the first element (that's being grouped) and the second element being the corresponding pairs to the grouped values from the `zip`

From this we go on to call when iterating by k,g

```
list(list(zip(*g))[1]
```

which returns the pair values for that group!

Comment: That list comprehension is precisely what I needed; albeit very confusing. Thank you for your help. Would you mind explaining what that list comprehension does in stages?

Comment: Iron, thank you so much for your help, answer and explanation. I very much appreciate your time and efforts! Take care; I hope to repay the favour one day.

Answer (score 1):

This uses no imports and is a 'pythonic' way.

```
J = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0]
B = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 6.0, 7.0, 0.5, 0.6, 8.0]

average_list = [round(sum([(B[index]) for index in [i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]])/len([i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]),2) for a in set(J)]

print(set(J))
print(average_list)

>>> {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}
>>> [0.8, 6.0, 7.0, 0.55, 8.0]
```

What i'm doing is:

**Step 1:**

First I get a non duplicate list J `for a in set(J)`

**Step 2:** I then iterate through this list and get all the indices for each number where it duplicates in the duplicate list(list J) `i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]]`

e.g for 1.0, indices would be `0,1,2` Note I have now created a list of indices

**Step 3:**

Note I am still on the first iteration in Step 2, In this new list of indices, I get all the matching indices elements for list B so for `1.0`, the indices were `0,1,2` so the matching indices elements from list B would be `0.7,0.8,0.9`

**Step 4:** I now get the sum of the matching indices elements list `sum([(B[index]) for index in [i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]])`,

and divide it by the length of this same list, which is
`len([i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]),2)`,

so overall it is `(sum([(B[index]) for index in [i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]])/len([i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]))`

**Step 5:** Now that I have this sum, I then round it because I was getting up to 7 decimals for some numbers.`[round(sum([(B[index]) for index in [i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]])/len([i for i, x in enumerate(J) if x == a]),2)`

the `,2` just rounds it to two decimal places, you can make this any number you want.

So **Steps** **1** to **5** are repeated for the iterations in **Step 1**

Also note every time you see code enclosed in `[]` it means all the code inside has generated a list (apart from `B[index]` which is just to get an element from a list, so typically the list `average_list` generated about 4 list, which were all iterated through.

I hope this helps, if there's any confusion feel free to ask.

Edit:

If you want to use it for unsorted list, do:

```
average_list = [round(sum([B[index] for index in [i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(B)) if x == a]])/len([i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(B)) if x == a]),2) for a in set(J)]
```

I added in two `sorted` key words, so that the list can be sorted.